# Bash reboot script with email and IP address

Tags: shell-script, cron, raspbian

I made a shell script to reboot my machine. The script sends an email with some information of the host and then reboots.

The script will be run by cron.

When I run the script from the terminal it runs pretty well, but when it runs using cron, the IP address and "servicos" are missing.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Carrega uptime
up=("$(uptime -p)")

# Carrega nome do host
host=("$(hostname)")

# Carrega IPs do host
meu_ip=("$(ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')")

# Carrega data/hora atual
data=("$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")")
hora=("$(date +"%T")")

# Carrega servicos iniciados durante o boot, ordenados alfabeticamente
servicos=("$(ls -1 /etc/rc$(runlevel| cut -d" " -f2).d/S* | awk -F'[0-9][0-9]' '{print " " $2}' | sort -k 3)")

### Define parametros de e-mail ###
email="myemail@address.com" # E-mail do destinatario do alerta
assunto=$host": [Alert] Restart ["$meu_ip"]" # Assunto do email

# Envio de email de alerta
printf "%b\n" "Sistema [$host] ($meu_ip) reiniciado em $data.\n
Uptime: $up\n
Carregado na inicializacao:\n$servicos" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$assunto" "$email"

# Aguarda 5s para que o email seja enviado corretamente
sleep 5

# Reinicia o equipamento
/sbin/reboot
```

I already tested awk too:

```
meu_ip=("$(ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')")
```

But still not working...

Example of a received email after cron (automatic) exec:

```
Sistema [raspberrypi] () reiniciado em 2016-09-26.

Uptime: up 1 minute

Carregado na inicializacao:
```

Example of a received email after terminal (manual) exec:

```
Sistema [raspberrypi] (192.168.8.121) reiniciado em 2016-09-26.

Uptime: up 30 minutes

Carregado na inicializacao:
 avahi-daemon
 bluetooth
 bootlogs
 cron
 dbus
 dhcpcd
 dphys-swapfile
 exim4
 motd
 ntp
 plymouth
 rc.local
 rmnologin
 rsyslog
 ssh
 triggerhappy
```

I'm currently using Raspbian based on Debian Jessie.

Comment: Are you setting an appropriate `PATH` anywhere? cron's default one is limited (commands like `runlevel` and `ifconfig` may be in `/sbin`)

Comment: @steeldriver, got it! Now it works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Defined the `PATH` inside the script and made some "cosmetic" changes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define caminho dos binarios
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Carrega uptime
up=("$(uptime -p | awk '{$1=""; sub("  ", " "); print}')")

# Carrega nome do host
host=("$(hostname)")

# Carrega IPs do host
meu_ip=("$(ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')")

# Carrega data/hora atual
data=("$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")")
hora=("$(date +"%T")")

# Carrega servicos iniciados durante o boot, ordenados alfabeticamente
servicos=("$(ls -1 /etc/rc$(/sbin/runlevel| cut -d" " -f2).d/S* | awk -F'[0-9][0-9]' '{print " Servico :-> " $2}' | sort -k 3)")

### Define parametros de e-mail ###
email="myemail@address.com"        # E-mail do destinatario do alerta
assunto=$host": [Alert] Restart ["$meu_ip"]" # Assunto do email

# Envio de email de alerta
printf "%b\n" "Sistema [$host] ($meu_ip) reiniciado em $data.\n
Uptime: $up\n
Carregado na inicializacao:\n$servicos" | mail -s "$assunto" "$email"

# Aguarda 10s para que o email seja enviado corretamente
sleep 10

# Reinicia o equipamento
reboot
```